# DSL connection using networkmanager in KDE does not seem to work

Tags: network-manager, kubuntu, dsl

I have installed Kubuntu 10.10 alongside windows 7. In kubuntu 10.10 i tried to connect to internet using the DSL connection tab in the networkmanger on the taskbar -> manage connection -> DSL. i gave the username, password, ip address(manually) etc. checked the box of "connect automatically". The system connection checkbox was grayed out so i could not do anything to it. Then i clicked apply. But the connection that had just created didn't appear in the available connections. As there was no connection named that i created using DSL tab i could not connect to internet.

I used to connect to internet using the same method in Ubuntu 's networkmanager.

Is this some kind of bug in kde's network manager ?
how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug: [Bug #447241](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plasma-widget-networkmanagement/+bug/447241) 
You can use `pppoeconf` to configure a DSL connection: [How to Set Up Kubuntu for DSL](http://www.ehow.com/how_6008277_set-up-kubuntu-dsl.html)

Comment: i can connect using pppoeconf however. But using GUI seems easy. The Bug was reported after karmic release. Both Kubuntu and Ubuntu had this problem. In Lucid and Maverick release of Ubuntu the bug has been fixed. But why not in Kubuntu?

Comment: Can this bug be fixed by simple source code change? Or editing some files ? I want to make GUI work.

Answer (score 1):

Not only in the Kubuntu but in Fedora(KDE) it seems that the same bug is present also.
It's really a BIG problem to new comers on the Linux system. Most of the guys who are new to Linux try to use KDE because of its beauty and I think the developers should fix this bug as soon as possible.